# submit button keeps refreshing page

Tags: php, html

I know this might be a little simple, but I can't see any wrong with my codes but its not working. The page just keep on refreshing when the submit button is clicked. I think it's not entering the `if(isset($_POST['sub']))` code. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add Client</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");
?>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<form method="post">
<center>
<h1>Add Client</h1>
<table>
<tr><td>Client Name</td><td><input name="cname" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Client Category</td><td><input name="cat" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Client Address</td><td><input name"add" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Client City</td><td><input name="city" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Person</td><td><input name="cper" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Details</td><td><input name="cdet" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sales Territory</td><td>
<?php
$a=mysql_query("select `sales-territory-no`, `sales-territory-name` from `sales-territory`") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<select name='terr'>";
while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
{   
    echo "<option value='".$b['sales-territory-no']."'>".$b['sales-territory-name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sales Person ID</td><td>
<?php
$c=mysql_query("select * from `sales`") or die(mysql_error());
echo"<select name='sales'>";
while($d=mysql_fetch_array($c))
{   
    echo "<option value='".$d['sales-no']."'>".$d['firstname'].' '.$d['lastname']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name"sub" value="Submit" />
</center>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{   
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo "alert(\"Hello!\");";
    echo "</script>";   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name="sub"
```

you're missing the = in the submit button code.

That should work

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. -___-

Comment: sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
```

with

```
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" /> or

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
```

If this answer is right then please mark it as an answer....